# How can I get the network status?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In react native, Is there a way to get the network status of the device? For example, I would like to know if the current device is online or offline. Also I would like to detect when de device get online or offline in order to show a message to the user or any other process that I need to run.

So far all I could find is to send a request to the API, and set a `catch` callback to the `fetch`, if there's not connection the `catch` callback will run, this seems to work but I'm wondering if there's a better way to solve this.

I would also like to know if the device is using wifi or lte connection.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## NetInfo API

Have a look at [React Natives NetInfo API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html). The following example is copied from the official documentation:

```
const ConnectionInfoCurrent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      connectionInfo: null,
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    NetInfo.addEventListener(
        'change',
        this._handleConnectionInfoChange
    );
    NetInfo.fetch().done(
        (connectionInfo) => { this.setState({connectionInfo}); }
    );
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    NetInfo.removeEventListener(
        'change',
        this._handleConnectionInfoChange
    );
  },
  _handleConnectionInfoChange: function(connectionInfo) {
    this.setState({
      connectionInfo,
    });
  },
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.connectionInfo}</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the connectivity manager to access the network state. You can read the WIFI and mobile data with the same approach.

```
public void checkInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (activeNetwork != null) {
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            Log.d(TAG, "checkInternet: " + "Connected to WIFI");
        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "checkInternet: " + "Connected to Mobile data");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkInternet: " + "Not connected");
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to add the permissions to your manifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Hope it helps!